# Visual Studio Debugger using wrong code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I am trying to debug my python code in Visual Studio but it is stepping and running through the wrong code!

I USED TO HAVE have something like

```
def method1(values):
    ret = str(values)
    return ret

value = method1([1,2]).
```

I wanted to fix it and change it to something like:

```
def method1(values):
    ret = ''
    for item in ret:
        ret = ret + str(value)
    return ret

value = method1([1,2])
```

but when i step through the code the arrow is pointing to empty lines, and the auto variable watch it showing that it is doing the original code.

I have deleted the file and created a new one with the same code. (copy and pasted code as it is part of a VERY large file)

I have removed it from the solution and re-added it

I have looked at the code in notepad and it is saved as the new code.

I have reset the PC

I cannot figure out why it is not running the code that I have written now!

I have never had this issue before. Any ideas?